# Errors with RSpec, Shouda, and Rails 3: undefined method `response_code'

Tags: rspec, shoulda, ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure why I am getting these errors, seemingly only on the Shoulda matcher tests.  Any advice would be helpful.

http://pastie.org/1020788

Comment: Please add your controller code into that pastie

Comment: It's just a def index; end.  I also have the standard index.html.erb view.  Works fine if I fire it up in a browser.

Comment: Also, they all pass when I explicitly set the subject.  subject { controller }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in Shoulda and has been filed in Lighthouse.